# assertEqual two dicts except one key

Tags: python, django, testing, assert

I need to test a function which will return an dict with `rest_framework.test.APITestCase's assertEqual` in `django`. The dict is something like this:

```
{
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "random": some random number
}
```

How can I check the returned dict with my suitable result except the `random` key?

I mean `assertEqual(a, result)` should return `True` if these two dicts are passed:

```
a = {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "random": 12
    }

result = {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "random": 24
    }
```

Is there anyway to make this kind of exceptions in `assertEqual` or I have to use `assert`?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to everyone, I got great solutions, But what if I got a list containing those dicts, like:

```
assertEqual(list_of_dicts, expected_result_list)
```

I mean in these two lists:

```
list1 = [
 d1,
 d2,
 d3
]

list2 = [
 d1,
 d2,
 d3
]
```

should be equal without considering the `random` key in each dict

Do I have to loop through the list and compare dicts one by one or there is a fastest solution for that as well?

Comment: Would you like to compare all dicts in the list to each other? ie should `[d1, d2, d3]` check `d1 == d2`, `d1 == d3` and `d2 == d3` ?

Comment: @DeepSpace No. only `d1 == d1`, `d2 ==d2`, ...

Comment: I'm not sure I follow then... why would `d1` not be equal to `d1`? it's the same dictionary

Comment: @DeepSpace Maybe I'm not clarifying myself. I mean `d1` from `list1` should be equal to `d1` from `list 2`. I'll edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a copy of the dictionaries and pop the random number from there

```
a_copy = a.copy()
a_copy.pop("random")
result_copy = result.copy()
result_copy.pop("random")

assertEqual(a_copy, result_copy)
```

If you don't want to preserve the original use `pop()` directly on the existing dictionaries.

If you have two lists of dicts you can iterate over both with `zip` and compare each pair

```
for l, r in zip(copy.deepcopy(list_of_dicts), copy.deepcopy(expected_result_list)):
    l.pop("random")
    r.pop("random")
    assertEqual(l, r)
```

Comment: Are you sure about that? As far as I know `dict.pop` returns the popped value

Comment: @Pynchia just notice myself, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than copying both and modifying both copies, you can copy and modify one of the dicts to correct the difference:

```
a_copy = a.copy()
a_copy['random'] = b['random']
assertEqual(a_copy, b)
```